# how to import components to add them to routes with Vue and VueRouter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

in my project I have a folder called views, for my views in a spa, what I try is to avoid the manual import of each element, is this possible?

to declare components I investigated this method.

```
const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], 
                files(key).default))
```

how to do this if the syntax is

```
import  Home from '../views/Home ';
```

I tried this, because this is the idea but it obviously marks me error, what would be the best solution?

```
const files = require.context('../views/', true, /\.vue$/i)
files.keys().map(key => {
    import  key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0] from '../views/'+  files(key);
})

/* Routers */
export default  [
/* Rutas de Venta venta */
{ 
    path: '/', 
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

[Chris Fritz](https://www.patreon.com/chrisvuefritz) had a talk where [explain it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lpemgMhi0k)

His presentation is in [github](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/7-secret-patterns)

I don't understand so much this code, but it works

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import upperFirst from 'lodash/upperFirst'
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase'

// Require in a base component context
const requireComponent = require.context(
    './components', false, /base-[\w-]+\.vue$/
);

requireComponent.keys().forEach(fileName => {
    // Get component config
    const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName)

    // Get PascalCase name of component
    const componentName = upperFirst(
        camelCase(filename.replace(/^\.\//,'').replace(/\.\w+$/, ''))
    )

    // Register component globally
    Vue.component(componentName, componentConfig.default || componentConfig)
})
```

Comment: That is the solution to register components with Vue.component, what I try is something else, with imports